# Pandas: New column value based on the matching multi-level column's conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have the following dataframe with multi-level columns

```py
In [1]: data = {('A', '10'):[1,3,0,1],
                ('A', '20'):[3,2,0,0],
                ('A', '30'):[0,0,3,0],
                ('B', '10'):[3,0,0,0],
                ('B', '20'):[0,5,0,0],
                ('B', '30'):[0,0,1,0],
                ('C', '10'):[0,0,0,2],
                ('C', '20'):[1,0,0,0],
                ('C', '30'):[0,0,0,0]
                }
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        df
Out[1]:
   A        B        C
  10 20 30 10 20 30 10 20 30
0  1  3  0  3  0  0  0  1  0
1  3  2  0  0  5  0  0  0  0
2  0  0  3  0  0  1  0  0  0
3  1  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0
```

In a new column `results` I want to return the combined column name containing the maximum value for each subset (i.e. second level column)

My desired output should look like the below

```py
Out[2]:
   A        B        C
  10 20 30 10 20 30 10 20 30      results
0  1  3  0  3  0  0  0  1  0  A20&B10&C20
1  3  2  0  0  5  0  0  0  0      A10&B20
2  0  0  3  0  0  1  0  0  0      A30&B30
3  1  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0      A10&C10
```

**For example the first row:**

For column **'A'** the max value is under column **'20'** &
for column **'B'** there is only 1 value under **'10'** &
for column **'C'** also it is only one value under **'20'** &
so the result would be `A20&B10&C20`

**Edit**: replacing "+" with "&" in the `results` column, apparently I was misunderstood and you guys thought I need the summation while I need to column names separated by a separator

**Edit2:**
The solution provided by @A.B below didn't work for me for some reason. Although it is working on his side and for the sample data on google colab.

somehow the `.idxmax(skipna = True)` is causing a `ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series`

I found a workaround by transposing the data before this step, and then transposing it back after.

```py
map_res = lambda x:  ",".join(list(filter(None,['' if isinstance(x[a], float) else (x[a][0]+x[a][1]) for a in x.keys()])))

df['results'] = df.replace(0, np.nan)\
                  .T\  # Transpose here
                  .groupby(level=0)\  # Remove (axis=1) from here
                  .idxmax(skipna = True)\
                  .T\  # Transpose back here
                  .apply(map_res,axis=1)
```

I am still interested to know why it was is not working without the transpose though?

Comment: But you are not including the values that are zero

Comment: @Dani Mesejo yes, zero originally were NaN values

Comment: Do you actually want the names of columns separate by "+",  or the sum?

Comment: @A.B separated by "+" or "&" not the sum. sorry it wasn't clear at 1st

Comment: @Nagib - `am still interested to know why it was is not working without the transpose though?` I think because depends of pandas versions, in some versions solution should be buggy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is replace `0` by `NaN`, so if use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) all rows with `NaN`s are removed. Then get indices by [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html), mapping second and third tuple values by `map` and aggregate `join` to new column per indices - first level:

```
df['results'] = (df.replace(0, np.nan)
                   .stack([0,1])
                   .groupby(level=[0,1])
                   .idxmax()
                   .map(lambda x: f'{x[1]}{x[2]}')
                   .groupby(level=0)
                   .agg('&'.join))
print (df)
   A        B        C            results
  10 20 30 10 20 30 10 20 30             
0  1  3  0  3  0  0  0  1  0  A20&B10&C20
1  3  2  0  0  5  0  0  0  0      A10&B20
2  0  0  3  0  0  1  0  0  0      A30&B30
3  1  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0      A10&C10
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df["results"] = df.groupby(level=0, axis=1).max().sum(1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   A        B        C       results
  10 20 30 10 20 30 10 20 30        
0  1  3  0  3  0  0  0  1  0       7
1  3  2  0  0  5  0  0  0  0       8
2  0  0  3  0  0  1  0  0  0       4
3  1  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0       3
```

Comment: unfortunately this is not what I want, I need to return both levels columns matching the max value.

Comment: @Nagib See my edit (`level=0`)

Comment: apparently I wasn't clear, I need the column names separated (i.e. A20&B10&C20)  not the sum of max values

Answer (score 1):

- Group by level 0 and axis=1
- You use idxmax to get max sub-level indexes as tuples (while skipping NaNs).
- Apply function to rows (axix-1) to concat names
- In function (that you apply to rows), Iterate on keys/columns and concatenate the column levels. Replace Nan (which have type 'float') with an empty string and filter them later.

You won't need df.replace(0, np.nan) if you initially have NaN and let them remain.

```
map_res = lambda x:  ",".join(list(filter(None,['' if isinstance(x[a], float) else (x[a][0]+x[a][1]) for a in x.keys()])))

df['results'] = df.replace(0, np.nan)\
                  .groupby(level=0, axis=1)\
                  .idxmax(skipna = True)\
                  .apply(map_res,axis=1)
```

Here's output

```
    A       B           C               results
10  20  30  10  20  30  10  20  30  
0   1   3   0   3   0   0   0   1   0   A20,B10,C20
1   3   2   0   0   5   0   0   0   0   A10,B20
2   0   0   3   0   0   1   0   0   0   A30,B30
3   1   0   0   0   0   0   2   0   0   A10,C10
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. but it is not working. I get the error "ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series"

Comment: can you please share exact line where the error is appearing

Comment: it appears in the last line (df['results'] = df.replace(0, np.nan)\
                  .groupby(level=0, axis=1)\
                  .idxmax(skipna = True)\
                  .apply(map_res,axis=1))


 "KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError: No axis named 1 for object type Series"

Comment: Are you sure you are applying it to Dataframe and df is a valid dataframe?

Comment: Here is a working example
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1K5l9ibmlNWbxNQiKgdOZQ8ytb2zD9Vok?usp=sharing

Comment: very weird!, could it be something related to python/pandas version? mine as follow, python:v3.8.8 & pandas:v1.2.4

Comment: I dont think so, It says that you are applying the operation to series instead of DF (e.g., on df['some-column'])

Comment: I could trace the problem to the .idxmax(skipna = True) part. still not working on my side while working flawlessly on google colab :(